# using Swing components in javafx if they're not in the NetBeans javafx palette

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, javafx

I'm just getting started with javafx in NetBeans, and I have it doing simple stuff (windows with buttons + the like) but would like to try something slightly more realistic.

The "Swing/AWT Components" palette has a whole bunch of stuff that the "JavaFX Script Code Clips" palette does not (it has Button, CheckBox, ComboBox, ComboBoxItem, Label, RadioButton, Slider, TextField, and ToggleButton). How do I add stuff to this palette?

I would like to try using some of the components in org-netbeans-swing-outline.jar

---

edit: Aha. I was missing the point somewhat: there are only some javafx-wrapped Swing components available in javafx.ext.Swing.*, so if you want one of the other Swing components you have to wrap them yourself.

Comment: what version of netbeans are you using?

Answer (score 0):

aha, I figured out what I needed to do:

There's a way to [wrap Swing components into a javafx component](http://javafx.com/samples/ExercisingSwing/index.html) using `javafx.ext.swing.SwingComponent.wrap()`